# maven - build once to generate separate war files for separate environment

Tags: maven, environment-variables, frontend

My pom.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-application</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.2.0</version>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>local</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>envType</name>
          <value>local</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <envType>local</envType>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>local2</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <envType>local2</envType>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>envType</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <envType>dev</envType>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>sit</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>envType</name>
          <value>sit</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <envType>sit</envType>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>uat</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>envType</name>
          <value>uat</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <envType>uat</envType>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <build>
    <finalName>my-application</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <nodeVersion>v6.10.0</nodeVersion>
              <npmVersion>3.10.10</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>bower install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>bower</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>gulp build</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>gulp</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>optimize --env ${envType}</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Front end maven plugin installs node, all required npm and bower packages and initiates the gulp task for optimizing all the front end code. Gulp places all the front end code into the below -

```
/src/main/webapp/index.html
/src/main/webapp/js/
etc
```

web.xml is at -

```
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Command to build the war package for local,SIT,DEV, etc environment -

```
mvn clean install -DenvType=local

mvn clean install -DenvType=sit

mvn clean install -DenvType=uat
```

This builds the war file - `my-application.war` in `/target` directory.

I need to run the maven command separately each time in order to build the war package for each environment. (because the front-end code uses separate environment variables for each environment).

How can I change the build process so that I need to build only once and maven takes care of running the gulp tasks for each environment (`gulp optimize --env ${envType}`) one after the other and produces separate war files in the target directory -

```
my-application-local.war
my-application-sit.war
my-application-uat.war
etc
```

I need maven to run the gulp task in sequence. I can make each run of gulp to output the front-end code to separate directories. The maven should pick from these separate directories and create separate war files. Not sure whether this is the right approach. Please let me know on this.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Comment: multienv-maven-pluging does not help me in running the gulp tasks in sequence for each environment separately